# How to make an expression clickable on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am writing a Twitter type client. I want stuff like @ and # clickable. When I click on it, I want it to do some sort of IBAction. I found this for OSX:

http://flyosity.com/mac-os-x/clickable-tweet-links-hashtags-usernames-in-a-custom-nstextview.php

This is along the lines of what I want to accomplish. Anything for iOS that is of this caliber?

Comment: Have you looked at Three20? I believe that it supports clickable links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this page http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/

Answer (score 4):

The best dropin solution I've found was this: https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel
Clean and simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can make any properly `formatted URLs` appear as blue underlined active links in a `UITextView` with the following code (in say `viewDidLoad`)

```
self.myTextView.editable = NO;
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

**Search for "Technical Q&A QA1495" in Xcode's Documentation and API Reference.**

Comment: +2 for your answer:)...it saved my time!!

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, I guess you could achieve it by using a UIWebView to display the content (which you have linkified, as per the "2: Finding The Interesting Parts" part of the blog post).

If you then prefix the hashtag links with a custom url scheme, like `myappopenshashtags://`, and register that url scheme for your app, you should be able to open your hashtags in whatever way you please.

Comment: i want a full native solution.

Comment: This is a "native" solution, thank you very much. If you can't see that, you don't know the word.