# How can I make clickable links like the Twitter and Facebook app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, uilabel, three20

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an expression clickable on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350390/how-to-make-an-expression-clickable-on-ios)

On Twitter and Facebook, usernames like @ and hashtags like # are clickable, and do something native within the app.

What is the best way to implement something like this? It would be nice if there was a drop in replacement for a UILabel for example.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772791/nsattributedstring-and-links-on-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)** project on github is a drop-in replacement for UILabel that supports embedding links. https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: This looks interesting. Would I be able to do my own handling when a link is clicked? For example, present a modal view controller?

Comment: I believe you'll have to write and register your own URL handler so that your application can handle the click. You may wish to also take a look at the Three20 project (https://github.com/facebook/three20/) as all of the view linkage is done via app-internal URLs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what Twitter does, but the Facebook app uses a library called Three20 to achieve Rich Text UILabels.  They have the ability to be formatted and have in-line hyperlinks.  You should specifically look at TTStyledTextLabel.

Check it out:
http://three20.info/